# How to write 'real' ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This works, but it is ugly ... who knows the 'real Ruby' version?

```
<% if @project %>
  <%= f.select :project_id, Project.all.collect {|p| [ p.project_name, p.id ]}, selected: @project.id %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.select :project_id, Project.all.collect {|p| [ p.project_name, p.id ]} , {include_blank: true}, class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `Project.pluck(:name, :id)`

Comment: This is not Ruby, but ERB (Embedded Ruby).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to move the options selection to your controller action.

```
@project_options = Project.select(:id, :project_name).all.collect {|p| [ p.project_name, p.id ]}
```

better

```
@project_options = Project.pluck(:name, :id)
```

In your view:

```
<%= f.select :project_id, @project_options, {selected: @project.id, include_blank: (@project ? false : true)}, class: (@project ? nil : "form-control") %>
```

Comment: Ok, your right. I assumed the select hasn't hundreds or thousends of options.

Comment: Normally it would not, but I think it is a good idea to assume it potentially could

Comment: What about `selected: @project.id`? That will throw an exception if `@project` is `nil`. And `class: "form-control"` also seems to depend on `@project`. It's probably clearer to just keep the if/else.

Comment: The bottleneck indeed is the exeption when `@project == nil`. That's the reason for if/else. I was wondering if there was a better way to forestall the exeption.